# How to parse the numbers before the JSON objects with GSON

Tags: java, gson

How can i parse this one with GSON? Because this one is starting with a number "1" and "2". I have made an object for the one starting with entity_id and that is working when i removed the outside json (with the "1" in it).

But I want to parse this whole bunch of code at ones. So what should I do to parse the "1" and "2" also? Something like String id and List innerobjects?

```
{
  "1": {
    "entity_id": "1",
    "status": "complete",
    "coupon_code": null,
    "shipping_description": "Flat Rate - Fixed",
    "customer_id": null,
    "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_grand_total": "3422.3800",
    "base_shipping_amount": "90.0000",
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_subtotal": "3332.3800",
    "base_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_total_paid": "3422.3800",
    "base_total_refunded": null,
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "grand_total": "3422.3700",
    "shipping_amount": "90.0000",
    "shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "store_to_order_rate": "1.0000",
    "subtotal": "3332.3700",
    "tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "total_paid": "3422.3700",
    "total_refunded": null,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": "3332.3800",
    "base_total_due": "0.0000",
    "shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "subtotal_incl_tax": "3332.3700",
    "total_due": "0.0000",
    "increment_id": "100000001",
    "base_currency_code": "EUR",
    "discount_description": null,
    "remote_ip": "472.15.1.83",
    "store_currency_code": "EUR",
    "store_name": "Main Website\nMain Website Store\nDefault Store View",
    "created_at": "2012-08-10 09:37:17",
    "shipping_incl_tax": "90.0000",
    "payment_method": "checkmo",
    "gift_message_from": null,
    "gift_message_to": null,
    "gift_message_body": null,
    "tax_name": null,
    "tax_rate": null,
  },
  "2": {
    "entity_id": "2",
    "status": "pending",
    "coupon_code": null,
    "shipping_description": "Flat Rate - Fixed",
    "customer_id": null,
    "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_grand_total": "1140.7900",
    "base_shipping_amount": "30.0000",
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_subtotal": "1110.7900",
    "base_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_total_paid": null,
    "base_total_refunded": null,
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "grand_total": "1140.7900",
    "shipping_amount": "30.0000",
    "shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "store_to_order_rate": "1.0000",
    "subtotal": "1110.7900",
    "tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "total_paid": null,
    "total_refunded": null,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": "1110.7900",
    "base_total_due": null,
    "shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "subtotal_incl_tax": "1110.7900",
    "total_due": null,
    "increment_id": "100000002",
    "base_currency_code": "EUR",
    "discount_description": null,
    "remote_ip": "182.11.7.52",
    "store_currency_code": "EUR",
    "store_name": "Main Website\nMain Website Store\nDefault Store View",
    "created_at": "2012-08-15 15:19:35",
    "shipping_incl_tax": "30.0000",
    "payment_method": "checkmo",
    "gift_message_from": null,
    "gift_message_to": null,
    "gift_message_body": null,
    "tax_name": null,
    "tax_rate": null,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map` for odd `"1", "2", ...` objects:

```
Map<String, Order> map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

Comment: Uhm.. do you have an example for me?

Comment: Map<String, Order> map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class); Like this you meant! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setFieldNamingStrategy( new FieldNamingStrategy() {
   @Override
   public String translateName( Field field ) {
       if( field.getName().equals( "myNewVariableName" ) ) {
          return "1";
       } else {
          return field.getName();
       }
}
} );
Gson gson = builder.create();
MyCustomClass queryResult = gson.fromJson( json, MyCustomClass.class );
```

Write now your custom gson class which i call in the example 'MyCustomClass'.
Add a field with the name 'myNewVariableName'. If Gson serialize or deserialize json or your custom class it use the FieldNamingStrategy and replace your field 'myNewVariableName' with '1'.
In this way you reduce the complete parsing by your self and reuse the power of gson for you well-formed field names like 'entity_id'.